# Add initial value in fromEvent resize observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I try to get an observable of the window innerWidth.

I set a `fromEvent` observable watching on resize event

```
public get nativeWindow(): Window {
  return window;
}

public getWindowSize(): Observable<number> {
  return fromEvent(this.nativeWindow, 'resize').pipe(
    map(event => (event.target as Window).innerWidth)
  );
}
```

I want to be able to get the initial value of window.innerWidth because resize won't fire until actual window resize.

I could use `BehaviorSubject` but it forces me to subscribe to `fromEvent` to next on the subject.

We tried use a `startWith(this.nativeWindow.innerWidth)` operator before the map but the map then doesn't get the event argument as Event but get the `startWith` number instead.

Is there any rxjs operator which could allow me initialize first number before getting actual resize events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the problem is that you need `map` to process the initial value but at the same time you need it to work with `Event` objects that are only emitted by `'resize'` event.

Well the easiest way is to just use `startWith` after `map`:

```
return fromEvent(this.nativeWindow, 'resize').pipe(
  map(event => (event.target as Window).innerWidth),
  startWith(this.nativeWindow.innerWidth)
);
```

or if this isn't possible (eg. the logic is more complicated) you can "mock" the object so `map` will process it like any other Event object.

```
return fromEvent(this.nativeWindow, 'resize').pipe(
  startWith({ target: { innerWidth: this.nativeWindow.innerWidth }}),
  map(event => (event.target as Window).innerWidth)
);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just startWith({ target: this.nativeWindow }), when the startWith is before the map?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `startWith` operator and pass an initial value to the observable

```
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

return fromEvent(this.nativeWindow, 'resize').pipe(
    startWith({ target: nativeWindow }),
    map(event => (event.target as Window).innerWidth)
);
```

Comment: Sorry. `{ target: nativeWindow }` must be applied instead of `nativeWindow.innerWidth`